# Husky refuses to eat dry biscuits unless it's something else like canned meat for dogs

Tags: dogs, eating

I have 2 female huskies, 1 of them usually loves their food, once it's put down, it's gone in seconds.

Last few weeks, we have had trouble with her (the one that loves her food) not eating.  We usually mix things up, sometimes it can be a dry meal from a bag, other times it can be some sort of meat roll, or meat from a tin.  She doesn't get excited for the food she used to love, but as soon as we start putting the other food in the bowl, she cries for it.

We have tried a few different brands of dry food, and will try one more next pay day.  Things are getting quite expensive trying different things.

Is she just being really picky and hoping to have the meat instead of the dry food?

I've read some information that I should stick to what I'm doing by placing the food down, leaving it for a little while, then picking it up so shes learns that what is put down is what she should be eating, but it doesn't seem to be working, she will just sit there.

Health wise, she looks fine, runs around in the garden like normal.

How long should I put up with her doing this, as it's coming up to day 4 or 5 now, and I'm about to break and just give her the meat, which is rather expensive for us.

Comment: I also have a fussy Husky. I sometimes put her dry kibble in a Kong, and run hot water through it for 30 seconds or so. Then she goes straight for it; it's the same food, just smells a bit more interesting, and the Kong makes it more interesting too. And more messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she's fine and would eat other stuff, I wouldn't worry too much. Huskies can be extremely nitpicking, but dogs won't starve to death, even if the food available isn't what they have in mind.

We've got two Huskies and both tend to not eat a lot or sometimes nothing at all for a few days, possibly related to weather and/or fur changes as it seems.

Getting them to drink is a lot more important. As with all things, if you really worry, ask your vet.